# Can a class-interface design from Python be mirrored in Rust?

Tags: class, rust

A pattern I use frequently when writing Python is using class-only designs. I'll create an abstract base class, consisting of only `classmethod` and `staticmethod` methods. From this base, I can derive subclasses with specialized behavior for these methods. Since each of these subclasses have the same interface, and don't have any instance methods, I can pass around the classes themselves to client code, as opposed to instances of those classes.

As a simple, yet real/relevant example, here's how I would tackle needing to support multiple file formats for config data:

```py
import abc
import yaml
import json

class ConfigReader(abc.ABC):
    @classmethod
    def from_file_path(cls, path: str):
        with open(path) as fo:
            return cls.from_string(fo.read())

    @classmethod
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def from_string(cls, s: str):
        pass

class YamlConfigReader(ConfigReader):
    @classmethod
    def from_string(cls, s: str):
        return yaml.load(s)

class JsonConfigReader(ConfigReader):
    @classmethod
    def from_string(cls, s: str):
        return json.loads(s)
```

Client code can then use the classes themselves in lieu of instances of those classes to do config parsing:

```py
import typing as tp

def read_config_file(path: str, config_reader: tp.Type[ConfigReader]):
    return config_reader.from_file_path(path)

print(read_config_file('config.yaml', YamlConfigReader))
print(read_config_file('config.json', JsonConfigReader))
```

I'm trying to do something similar to the above in Rust, but I seem to be running into issues. My initial approach used traits and associated methods:

```
use std::path::Path;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::Read;
use std::io::Error;

pub trait ConfigReader {
    fn from_str<S: AsRef<str>>(s: S) -> Result<String, Error>;

    fn from_file<P: AsRef<Path>>(p: P) -> Result<String, Error> {
        let p = p.as_ref();
        let mut f = File::open(p)?;

        let mut buffer = String::new();
        f.read_to_string(&mut buffer)?;

        Self::from_str(buffer)
    }
}

pub struct YamlConfigReader;
pub struct JsonConfigReader;

impl ConfigReader for YamlConfigReader {
    fn from_str<S: AsRef<str>>(_s: S) -> Result<String, Error> {
        Ok("dummy".to_string())
    }
}

impl ConfigReader for JsonConfigReader {
    fn from_str<S: AsRef<str>>(_s: S) -> Result<String, Error> {
        Ok("dummy".to_string())
    }
}

fn read_config_file<P: AsRef<Path>>(p: P, config_reader: &ConfigReader) -> Result<String, Error> {
    config_reader.from_file(p)
}

fn main() {}
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=ed1eae1aa225c0f708bd47eba167017e&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015))

This gives me the error:

```
error[E0038]: the trait `ConfigReader` cannot be made into an object
  --> src/main.rs:37:1
   |
37 | fn read_config_file<P: AsRef<Path>>(p: P, config_reader: &ConfigReader) -> Result<String, Error> {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `ConfigReader` cannot be made into an object
   |
   = note: method `from_str` has no receiver
   = note: method `from_file` has no receiver
```

Is this sort of pattern possible in Rust? If not, what are some ways I can emulate this sort of behavior of decoupled, modular, stateless interfaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Rust, you would treat a type parameter as, well, a type parameter:

```
fn read_config_file<P: AsRef<Path>, C: ConfigReader>(p: P) -> Result<String, Error> {
    C::from_file(p)
}
```

This limits the dynamisms of such constructs.